# How to pass a struct containing char* in java using JNA and avoiding the data copy?

Tags: java, c++, c, struct, jna

I am writing a java application that will access to C++ dll usnig JNA. So I prepared a C dll to communicate between the JNA and C++ thrid party dll. I have these two structs:

C code:

```
    struct Struct1
    {
    uint32_t Size;
    unsigned char* Data;
    };
    struct Struct2
    {
    uint32_t Struct1_Nbr;
    Struct1* struct1_elements;
    };
    bool Open(char* fileName, Struct2** struct2);
```

Now I am writing the corresponding JNA code in java application and I want to access the "unsigned char* Data" without copying this data as it is a large amount of Data.
How can I use the "Memory" or the "Pointer" JNA types to do this task?

Here is my attempt:

```
    public class Test
    {
    public static class Struct1 extends com.sun.jna.Structure {        
    public Struct1(){}
    public Struct1(Pointer pointer){
        super(pointer);
        read();
    }

    public static class Struct1ByValue extends Struct1 implements com.sun.jna.Structure.ByValue{};
    public int Size;
    public Memory Data;
    public static class Struct1ByReference extends Struct1 implements com.sun.jna.Structure.ByReference{}

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Arrays.asList("Size", "Data");
    };

public static class Struct2 extends com.sun.jna.Structure {    
    public Struct2 (){}
    public Struct2 (Pointer pointer){
        super(pointer);
        read();
    }
    public int Struct2_Nbr;
    public Struct1.Struct1ByReference struct1_elements = new Struct1.Struct1ByReference();

    public static class Struct2ByValue extends Struct2 implements com.sun.jna.Structure.ByValue{};
    public static class Struct2ByReference extends Struct2  implements com.sun.jna.Structure.ByReference{}

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Arrays.asList("Struct1_Nbr", "struct1_elements"));
    };
}
    public interface StructureProtocol extends com.sun.jna.Library{
    Boolean Open(String fileName, PointerByReference struct2);
    }
    public StructureProtocol lib;
    public Test(){
    this.lib = (StructureProtocol) Native.loadLibrary("TestAPI", StructureProtocol.class);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Test test = new Test();
    PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();

    test.lib.Open("filePath", pref);
    Pointer ptr = pref.getValue();
    Struct2 struct2= new Struct2(ptr);
    Struct1[] struct1_array= (Struct1[])(struct2.struct1_elements).toArray(struct2.struct1_Nbr);
    System.out.println("struct1_array[0]: Size = " + struct1_array[0].Size);
    System.out.println("struct1_array[0]: Data= " + struct1_array[0].Data);
    }
    }
```

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: What does your attempt get you? An Error? Unexpected Result?

Comment: I get an expected result: System.out.println("Struct2.struct1_Nbr == " + struct2.struct1_Nbr); returns Struct2.struct1_Nbr == 0. so I have an exeption in this instruction "Struct1[] struct1_array= (Struct1[])(struct2.struct1_elements).toArray(struct2.struct1_Nbr);"

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Solutiuon, first Draft:

1. Declare a Class in java that extends Structure

   > **(com.sun.jna.Structure)**

   (all fields in the class **must** be public or you get an error, that the size of the structure extended class can't be measured)

   ```
   public class Struct1 extends Structure{
       public int Size;
       public String Data;  
   }
   ```
2. Declare and define a method in the C Dll, that takes a pointer to the structure as an argument (I created a structure and filled it with values for testing)

   ```
   void __declspec(dllexport) GetStruct(Struct1* a){
   Struct1 s;
   s.Size = 9;
   s.Data = "Output";
   *a = s;
   }
   ```
3. I assume that you already successfully connected the java app to the c dll, so i skip that part(if my assumption is wrong, tell me in the comments and i edit my answer)
4. If you add these lines to your java code (note cdll is the handle to my C library)

   ```
   Struct1 test = new Struct1();
   cdll.GetStruct(test);
   System.out.println("Struct1: " + test.Size + " " + test.Data);
   ```

You should get the data from the Structure s in the C Dll.

Comment: Using `String` to represent an arbitrary block of data is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the Data field points to arbitrary data, use a `Pointer`.  If the native side allocates, then you do nothing.  If the Java side allocates, use a `Memory` object assigned to that field.

As for the `struct*` and `struct**`, it'd be useful to see some native code using those constructs in order to tell what they represent, since there is some ambiguity (`struct*` could be a pointer to a single struct, or a pointer to a contiguous array of them).  `struct**` could be storage allocated for the return of a `struct*`, or it may be something else.